# confusion with combinations: number of delegations with at least one woman

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> A delegation of 4 people is to be selected from 5 women and 6 men. Find the number of possible delegations if there is at least one woman.

Why is my solution incorrect?: $5C1 \cdot 10C3$

Do I have to work out each possibility and then add the answers. I recall solving some questions previously directly and getting the right answer.

Comment: What should the right answer be? Or: how do you know it is wrong?

Comment: 315 is the right answer

Comment: Say there are four women A,B,C,D and you choose A from the first 5, B and two mens from the other. You could get the same combination if you choose B first, then A and two men from the other, but you want to count it once.

Comment: If you remain unconvinced, suppose there are just four women total and no men.  We wish to choose a delegation of four people such that we have at least one woman.  It should be obvious that there is exactly one way to do this, simply by taking each available person.  According to your mistaken formula however you might have thought it was $\binom{4}{1}\cdot \binom{3}{3}$.  The answer you came up with was the number of possible delegations such that you have a female leader for the delegation distinct from the other members.

Answer (score 5):

Your "solution" overcounts.

If you first select one woman and then $3$ from the remaining persons then a specific outcome will turn up more than once.

E.g. "first woman A and then B,C,D where B is also a woman" and "first woman B and then A,C,D" both give outcome A,B,C,D so this outcome is counted more than once.

The correct answer is $$\binom{11}4-\binom64$$i.e.  then number of all possibilities minus the number of possibilities where all selected persons are men.